# Two columns into One single cell SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, correlated-subquery

```
Select COALESCE(
(Select Convert(nvarchar(20),Count(ID))+' '+'Adult(s) - ' From TourPerson Where BookingID = 1 And [Type] = 1),
(Select Convert(nvarchar(20),Count(ID))+' '+'Child(s)' From TourPerson Where BookingID = 1 And [Type] = 2)  
) as TotalPassengers
```

I want to take it in below mentioned format

1 Adult -  0 Children

now it is only giving adults

Comment: Give some sample data and wanted output.

Comment: coalesce will not combine 2 fields, coalesce is a function to replace null values with other values

Comment: @t-clausen.dk  If i had  done wrong sorry i will delete that link, Thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when [Type] = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as NumAdults,
       sum(case when [Type] = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as NumChildren
from TourPerson
where BookingId = 1;
```

You can do the formatting in the application layer.  If you really want this as a string, I would suggest using `replace()`:

```
select replace(replace('<a> Adult - <c> Children',
                       '<a>', sum(case when [Type] = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
                      ),
               '<c>', sum(case when [Type] = 2 then 1 else 0 end)
              )
from TourPerson
where BookingId = 1;
```

I find that it is easier to control the format of the resulting string using `replace()`, rather than concatenating a bunch of expressions together.

Answer (score 0):

for sql server 2012

```
Select concat(
(Select Convert(nvarchar(20),Count(ID))+' '+'Adult(s) - ' 
From TourPerson 
Where BookingID = 1 And [Type] = 1),
(Select Convert(nvarchar(20),Count(ID))+' '+'Child(s)' 
From TourPerson 
Where BookingID = 1 And [Type] = 2)  
) as TotalPassengers
```